# Efficiency of iterators in unordered_map (C++)

Tags: c++, iterator, unordered-map

I can't seem to find any information on this, so I turn to stackoverflow.  How efficient are the iterators of std::tr1::unordered_map in C++?  Especially compared to, say, list iterators.  Would it make sense to make a wrapper class that also holds all the keys in a list to allow for efficient iteration (my code does use a lot of iteration over the keys in an unordered_map).  For those who will recommend boost, I can't use it (for whatever reasons).

Answer (score 9):

I haven't checked TR1, but N3035 (C++0x draft) says this:

> All the categories of iterators
>   require only those functions that are
>   realizable for a given category in
>   constant time (amortized). Therefore,
>   requirement tables for the iterators
>   do not have a complexity column.

The standard isn't going to give an efficiency guarantee other than in terms of complexity, so you have no guaranteed comparison of `list` and `unordered_map` other than that they're both amortized constant time (i.e., linear time for a complete iteration over the container).

In practice, I'd expect an `unordered_map` iterator to be at least in the vicinity of `list`, *unless* your hashmap is very sparsely populated. There could be an O(number of buckets) term in the complexity of the complete iteration. But I've never looked at even one implementation specifically of `unordered_map` for C++, so I don't know what adornments to expect on a simplistic "array of linked lists" hashtable implementation. If you have a "typical" platform test it, if you're trying to write code that will definitely be the fastest possible on all C++ implementations then tough luck, you can't ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you can't say for sure if something is efficient enough unless you've tried it and measured the results.  I can tell you that the standard library, TR1, and Boost classes have had tons of eyes on them.  They're probably as fast as they're going to get for most common use cases.  Walking an container is certainly a common use case.

With all that said, you need to ask yourself a few questions:

1. What's the clearest way to say what I want?  It may be that writing a wrapper class adds unneeded complexity to your code.  **Make it correct first, then make it fast.**
2. Can I afford the extra memory and time to maintain a `list` in parallel with the `unordered_map`?
3. Is `unordered_map` really the right data structure?  If your most common use case is traversal from beginning to end, you might be better off with `vector` because the memory is guaranteed to be contiguous.

Answer (score 4):

The unordered_map iterator basically just has to walk over the internal tree structure of the hashtable. This just means doing some pointer following, and so should be pretty efficient. Of course, if you are walking an unordered_map a lot, you may be using the wrong data structure in the first place. In any case, the answer to this, as it is for all performance questions, is for you to time your specific code to see if it is fast enough.

Comment: _"The unordered_map iterator basically just has to walk over the internal tree structure of the hashtable. This just means doing some pointer following, and so should be pretty efficient."_ That's not exactly scientific, is it?

Comment: "the internal tree structure of the hashtable"
It sounds like you're thinking of a treemap. This is a hashmap, and it is not a tree. Usually it'd be an array with a lot of empty cells and a few linked lists in some of the filled cells.

Comment: It's shocking that this is the most-upvoted answer. A std::map has a tree structure. A std::unordered_map does not. It's easy to see why a map's iterator works in linear time over the whole map. Whereas it's harder for an unordered_map to do that unless it manages a linked list overlay as overhead for all insert/remove operations (which then give nodes trivial "next" operations through the linked list which corresponds to all elements in the hash table).

Answer (score 3):

Answered by the benchmarks here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25027750/1085128
unordered_map is partway between vector and map for iteration. It is significantly faster than map.